# Sanitize with Angular translation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation

Either angular-translate or angular-gettext, I can't seem to find a better way to provide translation for these cases, say, take gettext as an example,

```
<p translate>Click <a href="http://www.x.co">here</a> for an example.</p>
```

If I sanitize the whole content of `<p>` before translating, what about the `a` tag? Is the only way to manage to cut the sentence in 3 pieces and translate each separately?

Comment: I created a similar open issue, see: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1135

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of doing it without 3 translations is like this:

HTML:

```
  <pre translate="WITH_LINK" translate-values="{linkStart: '<a href=\'http:www.x.co\'>', linkEnd: '<\a>'}"></pre>
```

JS:

```
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'WITH_LINK': 'Click {{linkStart}}here{{linkEnd}} for an example.'
  });
```

This way your HTML code remains in your template so you should be safe.

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dYGkI4rVDYlJWe19nD06?p=preview